# How to do multiple aggregations in kibana?

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I have multiple date fileds in my kibana index. of which i want to plot my data over two date histogram fields independently to show a trend . i want to do it in a single graph. But kibana does not have option to do more than one aggregation in a single visualization.
Is there any way to do ?

Problem specific Description:
i have bugs as data in my elastic index. in each row there is a filed 'big creation date' and another date field is also there named 'resolved date' .
if bug is not resolved then resolved date is null 
i want to plot trend of bugs ,created and resolved over monthly in a single graph.
problem is , if i am choosing creation date as aggregation then it is taking those rows corresponds to creation date , it is not taking resolved date as independent aggregation.
Any other way to solve this problem?

EDIT:
Solved it using Timelion kibana plugin , where you can use multiple date fileds in X- axis independently.
more about timelion https://github.com/elastic/timelion/blob/master/FUNCTIONS.md#holt

Answer (score 0):

A Range can be used like this , does it help
"range" : {
         "timestamp" : {
           "from" : null,
           "to" : "2016-12-03T00:37:39.00Z",
           "include_lower" : true,
           "include_upper" : true
         }
       }
     }, {
       "range" : {
         "timestamp" : {
           "from" : "2016-11-23T00:37:39.00Z",
           "to" : null,
           "include_lower" : true,
           "include_upper" : true
         }
       }
     }

Comment: can you please explain, how to use it? Becasue in kibana json input i am not able to give two queries like this..

Comment: This is from elastic search. My understanding is , if we add any filter it will add a query in json format. Edit that query and use it like this.